# Getting just the file name from full path

Tags: regex, perl

I need to get from a full file path just the name of the file. I've tried to use:

`$out_fname =~ s/[\/\w+\/]+//;`

but it "eats up" also purts of the file name.

example:

for a file: 
`/bla/bla/folder/file.part.1.file`,
it returned:
`.part.1,file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other answers, but just wanted to explain the mistake in your pattern.  Regex is tricky, but worth it to learn well.

The square brackets defines a class of objects that will match.  In your case, it will match with the forward slash, a *word character* (from the `\w`), the `+` character, or the forward slash character (this is redundant).  Then you are saying to match 1 or more of those.  There are multiple strings that could match.  It will match the earliest starting character, so the first `/`.  Then it will grab as much as possible.

This is not what you intended clearly. For example, if you had a `.` in one of your directory names, you would stop there. `/blah.foo/bar/x.y.z` would return `.foo/bar/x.y.z`.

The way to think of this is that you want to match all characters up to and including the final `/`.

All characters then slash: `/.*\//`

But to be safer, add a caret at front to make sure it starts there: `/^.*\//`

And to allow forward and backslashes, make a class for that: `/^.*[\/\\]/` (i.e. [elusive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4154070#4154099)).

A *really* good reference is [Learning Perl](http://books.perl.org/book/237).  There are about 3 really good regex chapters.  They are applicable to non-Perl regex users as well.

Comment: another alternative is to anchor at the end of the string, and match everything that isn't a directory separator (using a negated class, `[^...]`), between a directory separator and the end of the string, e.g. `$out_fname =~ m{[\/\\]([^\/\\]+)$}; my $filename_only = $1;`

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

```
use File::Basename;

my $path = "/bla/bla/folder/file.part.1.file";
my $filename = basename($path);
```

Comment: Not least, it will make your script portable on other operating systems.

Comment: Yeah, don't use regex when there's a built in function.  regex is expensive but sometimes you gotta pay it.

Comment: File::Basename is in Core (i.e. ships with Perl), but I wouldn't think of that as 'built in', only those functions in `perldoc perlfunc`.

Answer (score 5):

Besides File::Basename, there's also [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Path-Class/), which can be handy for more complex operations, particularly when dealing with directories, or cross-platform/filesystem operations. It's probably overkill in this case, but might be worth knowing about.

```
use Path::Class;

my $file = file( "/bla/bla/folder/file.part.1.file" );
my $filename = $file->basename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split` on the directory separator is another alternative. This has the same caveats as using a regex (i.e. with filenames it's better to use a module where someone else has already thought about edge cases, portability, different filesystems, etc, and so you don't need matching on both back- and forward-slashes), but useful as another general technique where you have a string with a repeated separator.

```
my $file = "/bla/bla/folder/file.part.1.file";
my @parts = split /\//, $file;
my $filename = $parts[-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *exactly* what I would expect it to *retain* in the given substitution. You are saying replace the longest string of slashes and word characters with nothing. So it grabs all the characters up until the first character you *didn't* specify and deletes them.

It's doing what you are asking it to do. I join with others in saying use [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename) for what you are trying to do.

But here is the quickest way to do the same thing:

```
my $fname = substr( $out_fname, rindex( $out_fname, '/' ) + 1 );
```

Here, it says find the *last* occurrence of `'/'` in the string and give me the text starting one after that position. I'm not anti-regex by any stretch, but it's a simple expression of what you actually want to do. I've had to do stuff like this for so long, I wrote a `last_after` sub:

```
sub last_after {
    my ( $string, $delim ) = @_;
    unless ( length( $string ) and my $ln = length( $delim )) {
        return $string // '';
    }
    my $ri = rindex( $string, $delim );
    return $ri == -1 ? $string : substr( $string, $ri + $ln );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to pull just the last field from a bunch of path names. This worked for me:

```
grep -o '/\([^/]*\)$' inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
$out_fname =~ s/^.*[\/\\]//;
```

It should remove everything in front of your filename.